# Kendo UI Tooltip Will Sometimes Remain Visible When it should Disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, kendo-ui

I have been playing around with this for quite some time, and I do not know what is wrong. When I have a few links in a row, and keep fluttering my mouse cursor over them quickly every so often a tooltip will remain visible when it should go away (it is visible even after the cursor is no longer on the link).

I believe my code is logically valid, can someone else see if they know why a tooltip here and there would remain visible?

For a link of this type:

`<a href="www.rich.com" onmouseover="tooltip(this); this.onmouseover=null;">Link</a>`

Here is the code:

```
function tooltip(e) {
    var ticketType = j$(e).data("ticket-type");
    var ticketID = j$(e).data("ticket-id");
    j$.post("/Some/Url/", { "ticketID":ticketID, "ticketType":ticketType },
        function(r) {
            var title = r["tt"];
            var tooltip = j$(e).kendoTooltip( { content: title, position: "top" } ).data("kendoTooltip");
        }).always(function() {
            if (j$(e).is(":hover")) { j$(e).data("kendoTooltip").show(); }
            else { j$(e).data("kendoTooltip").hide(); }
        });

    j$(e).hover(function() {},
        // Handler for when the pointer is leaving an element
        function(e) {
            if (j$(e.target).data("kendoTooltip") != undefined) {
                j$(e.target).data("kendoTooltip").hide();
                .log(e.target.innerHTML + ": was hidden.");
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that sometimes you mouseout before ajax post returns, therefore the tooltip is shown after you leave a link.  As well as hiding on mouseout, how about setting a data attribute on the target link so that the AJAX return can check the attribute before showing the tooltip:

```
function tooltip(e) {
    j$(e).data("hover", "true"); //turn on hover data-attribute
    var ticketType = j$(e).data("ticket-type");
    var ticketID = j$(e).data("ticket-id");
    j$.post("/Some/Url/", { "ticketID":ticketID, "ticketType":ticketType },
        function(r) {
            var title = r["tt"];
            var tooltip = j$(e).kendoTooltip( { content: title, position: "top" } ).data("kendoTooltip");
        }).always(function() {
            if (j$(e).data("hover") == "true") { j$(e).data("kendoTooltip").show(); }
            else { j$(e).data("kendoTooltip").hide(); }
        });

    j$(e).hover(function() {},
        // Handler for when the pointer is leaving an element
        function(e) {
            j$(e).data("hover", "false"); //turn offhover data-attribute
            if (j$(e.target).data("kendoTooltip") != undefined) {
                j$(e.target).data("kendoTooltip").hide();
                .log(e.target.innerHTML + ": was hidden.");
            }
        }
    );
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/IsACU)**

NOTE: demo uses a setTimeout to fake an ajax call

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't see the difference between your `if (j$(e).data("hover") == "true")` and my `if (j$(e).is(":hover"))`. Can you further explain?

Comment: @RichieEpiscopo, if the browser works properly, they should work the same, if some browsers implement hover detection differently, you manually setting a data-attribute on mousout might be more consistent across browsers. Has it made a difference?